# python - send a command with 3 backslashes

Tags: python, backslash

Editing to make question short and precise.

```
y = 7
command_to_send = 'command=\\\\\\"set value {0}\\\\\\\"'.format(y)
```

How can I get output of `command_to_send` as `command=\\\"set value 7\\\"` so that I can pass `command_to_send` to some other function.

Comment: What do you mean by send? Execute?

Comment: in order to have a backslash read you need to 'escape' it with another one. So 3 becomes 6 . That being said, you shound probably correct quotation.

Answer (score 3):

Using a raw string:

`command = r"\\\"`

Using a regular string:

`command = "\\\\\\"`

Comment: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` will occur in your raw string.  You cannot end a raw string with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = '\\\\\\"set value 0\\\\\\\"'

print("command={0}".format(command))
```

Produces output:

```
command=\\\"set value 0\\\"
```

If you want to assign you value from a variable, then you can do this:

```
y = 7
command_to_send = 'command=\\\\\\"set value {0}\\\\\\\"'.format(y)

print(command_to_send)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If I use x = command + xyz, it outputs 6 backslashes. But the print gives desired output as shown above.

Comment: just adding additional comment. I thought of passing the value in command like this and tried splitting it as below: Except print, it outputs all backslashes

y = 0
first_half = 'command=\\\\\\'
second_half = "\\\\\\"
command_to_send = first_half + "set value " + y + second_half

Comment: Hi.  I've extended my answer to allow you to assign the value from a variable.

Comment: I have to pass the 'command_to_send' output as an argument to some to other function but not print it.

Comment: You don't have to print it - I only did that to illustrate that the command_to_send contains the correct value. Side note: be sure not to use this approach for building SQL commands because it is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: the "command_to_send" still outputs all 6 backslashes with your 2nd example.